# Синхронизация с файлами другого сайта

Tags: php, include, синхронизация, synchronized

Не могу понять как реализовать синхронизацию моего файла sync.php, который должен находиться на домене(сайте) mysite.ru с другим моим проектом который находится по адресу sequrity.ru (для примера). Собственно сам код sync.php:

```
<?php
include "http://sequrity.ru/config.php";
include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/core.php";

//Checking if the visitor is in the Whitelist
$wtable = $prefix . 'ip-whitelist';
$wquery = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT ip FROM `$wtable` WHERE ip='$ip'");
$wrow   = mysqli_num_rows($wquery);
if ($wrow == "0") {

    //Ban System
    include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/ban-system.php";

    //Checking if Project SECURITY is enabled
    $table  = $prefix . 'settings';
    $squery = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `$table`");
    $srow   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($squery);
    if ($srow['realtime_protection'] == "Yes") {
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/sqli-protection.php";
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/massrequests-protection.php";
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/spam-protection.php";
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/content-protection.php";
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/badbots-protection.php";
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/fakebots-protection.php";
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/headers-check.php";
        include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/tor-detection.php";
    }

}

include "http://sequrity.ru/modules/optimizations.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начало стоит подчеркнуть что

```
include "http://sequrity.ru/config.php";
```

Вернет вам не сам скрипт вызываемого файла а арезультат его выполнения.

В данном случае вы можете решеить эту проблему несколькими путями.

1. Используйте Git. Это самый верный способ решения этой проблемы.
2. Используйте NFS(Network File System) – это сетевая файловая система, позволяющая пользователям обращаться к файлам и каталогам, расположенным на удалённых компьютерах, как если бы эти файлы и каталоги были локальными. Тоесть вы файл изменяете в одном файле к которому по сети подключены обе вебсайта.
3. Выше переведённые варианты вам помогут только лишь в том случае если у вас выделенный сервер. Но если это не так, то скорее всего вам прядётся синхронизировать эти файлы вручную. Для начало стоит подчеркнуть что эти файлы необходимо передавать по сети в зашифрованном состоянии дабы избежать утечки исходного кода. Кроме того вам необходимо определить когда именно файлы будут синхронизироваться. Это можно реализовать следующим образом
   На одном сервере у вас есть файл http://mysait.ru/get_encripted_file.php который возвращает зашифрованный исходный код а над другом сайте sync.php кто его принимает, расшифровывает и сохраняет.

Вот пример get_encripted_file.php

```
    /**
 * @param $string
 * @return string
 */
function encrypt($string)
{

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);

    return $output;
}

$sourceCode = file_get_contents('file_for_encrypt.php');
echo $encryptedSourceCode = encrypt($sourceCode);
```

А вот это код sync.php - собственно это и есть скрипт который будет скачивать скрипт, расшифровывать и сохранять его

```
/**
 * @param $string
 * @return string
 */
function decrypt($string)
{
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);

    return $output;
}

$sourceCode = file_get_contents('http://mysait.ru/get_encripted_file.php');

file_put_contents('save_to_this_file.php', $sourceCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете так делать, тем более через `http` протокол. Сайт никогда не должен выдавать исходные скрипты сайта - иначе это было бы большой дырой в безопасности.

Что вы можете сделать для синхронизации — например, вы можете автоматически или вручную копировать нужные файлы с сервера на сервер, по `ftp` или `ssh`.